# How can I encrypt a read-only adobe acrobat file?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, zip, adobe-acrobat, read-only

My brokerage kindly decided to mark my account statement as read-only for my benefit. But, now when I open the statement in Acrobat Pro X in Windows 7, the Encrypt option is grayed out. How can I make this pdf file modifiable so that I may encrypt it inside Adobe Acrobat Pro X? I'd rather not create a zip file to enclose and encrypt if it possible.

Comment: 1)I made a suggestion to change your title per the answer you have given. 2)The supplied answer you provided will not always work on certain encrypted files, your answer is a "work-around" and should not always be relied upon based on the encryption.

Comment: @graphicsman: Why on earth would you change the title to "DEcrypt", when the question, the tags, the answer, etc., mentions "ENcryption"?

Comment: Because his answer is incorrect.  Acrobat will not allow you to add a second level security feature (per my understanding) upon a `.pdf` file set to read-only.  You must remove the read-only feature and then add your encryption.  His answer displays how to go about removing the read-only by technically creating a new file.

Comment: also, as stated in my answer, if his `.pdf` file was a true encryption for read-only he would not be allowed to do any modification with the document.

Comment: @graphicsman I also cannot understand why the question should now read "DEcrypt"?  The file and question are about adding encryption, not removing it.  What about my answer is incorrect, it worked when I did it, how is creating a new file not a solution that is correct?

Comment: @graphicsman I tried your solution it does not work for me, whereas, the one I posted is working for me.

Comment: @graphicsman One of the most important aspects of editing posts is to keep the original intention. The OP clearly means *encryption*, as can also be read in the question's body. Please respect that. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies for a bad edit but the op's thread answser is vague and i was trying to correct it.  There are many types of adobe read-only options and his answer is a work-around and if someone is going to read this in the future they will try it and the answer may not work.  I was trying to help improve the answer with the question and explain what the OP had left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the read-only file open in Acrobat, under the `Create` menu choose `Combine Files into a Single PDF...` then is the dialog choose the menu `Add Files...` -> `Add Open Files...`  and choose the read-only file, click `Add Files` button then click `Combine Files` button, and voila, your file is no longer read-only and can be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Mikhail's XmlStarlet in Adobe Acrobat 9 as an example:

Open PDF:
[image]

Use the shortcut `Ctrl+D` (for windows) and this screen will pop-up

[image]

**It is to be noted depending on the encryption type you can remove the secured feature in Change Settings**

[image]

---

To secure a `.pdf`

[image]

Password Security

[image]

Certificate Security

[image]

There is a 3rd option that requires Adobe LifeCycle.

Comment: This does not work for me.